# Rails + Devise running into orm_adapter-0.5.0/lib/orm_adapter/to_adapter.rb:5: warning: toplevel constant OrmAdapter referenced by User::OrmAdapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When running my Rails (5.2.0.beta1) app and using Devise I cannot log in as a user or confirm a registration. The error I get is

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2018-01-17 15:19:45 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"some-token-pV6YfBfiXs6DxxJKoBoVLU4GNJtXUY3oAQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"my@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Einloggen"}
/Users/me/.gem/gems/orm_adapter-0.5.0/lib/orm_adapter/to_adapter.rb:5: warning: toplevel constant OrmAdapter referenced by User::OrmAdapter
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for OrmAdapter:Module):

orm_adapter (0.5.0) lib/orm_adapter/to_adapter.rb:5:in `to_adapter'
devise (4.3.0) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:267:in `find_first_by_auth_conditions'
devise (4.3.0) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:263:in `find_for_authentication'
devise (4.3.0) lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:196:in `find_for_database_authentication'
devise (4.3.0) lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb:8:in `authenticate!'
```

The configuration is fairly standard. The call to_adapter is in the gems and I am not actually doing anything with it myself.
The orm_adapter gem is pretty old but appears to be stable.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever had corrupted the orm_adapter gem. I uninstalled it

```
gem uninstall orm_adapter
```

and then re-installed it and that solved the problem

```
gem install orm_adapter
```